# How to show two echoes in one line

Tags: php, html, echo

How to make them appear in one line. I saw some other post which says to use `echo -n` but if I use it, it would give me an error

I want the "Name" and textbox to have some spacing in between, so I can align the other textboxes below.

```php
echo "<p style='width:50%'>Name:</p>";
echo "<input type='text' name='name' value='$row[Name]'/>";
```

[image]

Comment: `echo -n` is `bash`, not `PHP`.

Comment: Don't put them in separate paragraphs if you want them on the same line.

Comment: This is rather a question about HTML. PHP is just the language used here to output HTML. It's the HTML that is rendered as two lines in the web page.

Comment: Arguably, it's a question about CSS.

Comment: I don't even think arguably.  It is a question about CSS and also about the semantic correctness of using <p> in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short snippet that uses `<input>` and `<label>`.  You can see they are on the same line.

```html
<div class="preference">
    <label for="input1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="input1">
</div>
```

If you need to align textboxes it gets more complicated, and you should use something more modern like grid layout:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
div.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap:5px;
}
div.container label       { text-align:right; }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <label>Label 1</label>
    <input type="text" id='input1'/>

    <label>Label 2</label>
    <input type="text" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a question about HTML, not PHP.

```php
echo "<p style='width:50%'>Name: <input type='text' name='name' value='{$row['Name']}'/></p>";
```

Comment: but the style will affect the textbox which I do not want

Comment: I want the "Name:" and textbox to have some spacing

Comment: Yes, you do that with css, not the php output, for multiple reasons, one being the modern  semantic separation between content and style.  CSS is complicated enough that your original question is not answerable with the information given.  If you can elaborate more I can mock up something.

Comment: Also, <p> is short for paragraph and specifically used to put things on different lines, ie, paragraphs.  I think you want <label>, and then you style the input and its label: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label